# How to maintain pip install options in requirements file made by pip freeze?

Tags: python, pip

I use a [pip requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) to maintain a list of dependencies for my projects.

I now find myself having to install a library using `pip install --install-option='some-setup.py.option'` **but** `pip freeze` doesn't record these options in its output which I save in my project's `requirements.txt`. This causes problems because a simple `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a new machine installs all the dependencies without supplying the required arguments for this one library, and I've lost the simple round-trip operation.

**So, my 2 part question is:**

- Is there a way to maintain pip install options in the pip freeze output somehow?
- If not, is there a way to manually hack the requirements file to add the install option? I'm ok with losing the round trip nature of `pip freeze` if I have to, and switching to manual maintenance of the requirements file. I've checked the [documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) but couldn't see anything to help.

**Unnecessary but possibly interesting details follow**

I want to install [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) but [without building the C extension](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html#installing-without-c-extensions) so I can use it asynchronously in an [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) based app.

Install as desired and build requirements.txt:

```
(test)day@office:~/test$ pip install pymongo --install-option='--no_ext'
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-2.1.1.tar.gz (199Kb): 199Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo
Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
(test)day@office:~/test$ pip freeze >  requirements.txt
(test)day@office:~/test$ cat requirements.txt
bottle==0.10.7
distribute==0.6.10
eventlet==0.9.16
greenlet==0.3.3
lxml==2.3.3
pymongo==2.1.1
simplejson==2.3.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

In new virtualenv, try to install same project from `requirements.txt`. pip builds the C extension for pymongo `:(`

```
(test2)day@office:~/test2$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
...
Downloading/unpacking pymongo==2.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading pymongo-2.1.1.tar.gz (199Kb): 199Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo
Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo
    building 'bson._cbson' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
...
Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
```

**Update**
[Issue 271](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/271) was opened against pip in April 2011 asking for the ability to specify per-line `--install-option` in requirements.txt. Please vote for the issue if you have the same problem.

Comment: if you manually add --install-option='--no_ext' to the requirements file, does it work? - if not I suspect you'll need to request that the pip developers add this functionality (which is a great idea!)

Comment: @d3vid That doesn't work I'm afraid. There's already a feature request for this, opened in April 2011: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/271. Please add your +1 there too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since version 7.0 (released [2015-05-21](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/)), pip has the ability to parse `--install-option` and `--global-option` from requirement files. It should now be possible to have the following line in your `requirements.txt`:

```
pymongo==2.1.1 --install-option='--no_ext'
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/docs/reference/pip_install.rst#id40) and [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2537).

Comment: Plz fix first link to https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/docs/reference/pip_install.rst#id40

Comment: What version of pip is this?

Comment: @hlin117 looks like version 7.0 onwards according to [the first link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/docs/reference/pip_install.rst#id40)

Comment: Using options in requirements.txt disables wheels for all modules. Thus means compiling evrything from scratch with dev dependencies.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, might be outdated?

Answer (score 7):

This might probably be too naïve, but if you're fine with managing the requirements and corresponding options manually -- why not maintain them as a small shell script that includes the entire pip incantation? Just a work-around until the feature request is listened to :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I feel a bit stupid for not having come up with this myself.  Thank you for posting this suggestion!

Comment: breaks the `requirements.txt` convention, which sucks because it breaks stuff downstream like, for example http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pip_state.html#salt.states.pip_state.installed. But yeah, that's apparently what's gonna be necessary here.