# Installing python dependency with condition ignore-requires-python using requirement.txt file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I want to install some python dependency using `requirement.txt` file. But as you can see to install a `client-py` I have to use some additional flags manly `extra-index-url`. How can I accommodate this in single requirement.txt file.

```
pip3 install \
    word2number==1.1 \
    setuptools==57.0.0 \
    numpy \
    scipy \
    pyproj

pip3 install --ignore-requires-python client-py --extra-index-url https://conda.abc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/noc-shared-pypi/simple
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain pip install options in requirements file made by pip freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874638/how-to-maintain-pip-install-options-in-requirements-file-made-by-pip-freeze)

Comment: @MohamedYasser This answer upto some extent. But as I mentioned I want to install `ndas-client-py` which require `--ignore-requires-python` flag as well. And I am getting `pip3: error: no such option: --ignore-requires-python` when using requirement.txt